# Restrict IoT Topic By User Attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot, amazon-cognito

I am working on a proof of concept using Amazon Cognito and AWS IoT and I need some help. I have everything working, I just need to lock things down. My Cognito User Pool is the only authentication provider I have for my Identity Pool.

I would like to restrict the IoT topics that can be subscribed to based on a custom attribute for the user in my User Pool. Is that possible with the IAM roles? I already can restrict it by entering the topic filter in a role, I just need to know if there is a variable I can use there.

For my use-case the application can have several organizations using the application, with each being completely separated from each other but using the same code and infrastructure. I am hoping I can specify the organization id on the users and then require all topics to have the user's organization id at the start.

I think what I am looking for is way beyond what IAM roles can do, but I want to check first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom attributes are not exposed as policy variables in IAM policies directly.

I think you can use the [Group support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html) in Cognito User Pools for this. You can assign users from different organizations to the group for that organization. The IAM role assigned to each of these groups can be the role with your locked down IoT policy.

Using the Federated Identities and User Pools [integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) you can get temporary AWS credentials for your users. Using the [role based access control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#using-tokens-to-assign-roles-to-users) feature in Cognito Federated Identities will make sure that the credentials are assumed using the role assigned to the Cognito User Pools group to which user belongs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, now if only there weren't a 25 groups per User Pool hard limit. Is there a way you can think of setup a single IAM role that would require the topic to start with the group name?